# jpa part of composite primary key also part of composite foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, orm

I'm having problems mapping thwo relations between three of my JPA entities. First of all, I show you the database tables involved:

1. Ciclista

   > idciclista (PK)
   >   (rest of fields...)
2. Prueba

   > idprueba (PK)
   >   (rest of fields...)
3. Inscripcion

   > idciclista (PK, FK in Ciclista.idciclista)
   >   **idprueba (PK, FK in Prueba.idprueba, FK in Variante.idprueba)**
   >   idvariante (FK in Variante.idvariante)
   >   (rest of fields...)
4. Variante

   > idprueba (PK, FK in Prueba.idprueba)
   >   idvariante (PK)
   >   (rest of fields...)

The problem is with the highlighted field, which is part of the composite PK of Inscripcion, a FK in Prueba and part of a composite FK in Variante, all at the same time.

My JPA Entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "inscripcion")
@IdClass(value=InscripcionPK.class)
public class Inscripcion {
    // ATTRIBUTES
    @Column
    private int dorsal;
    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date fechaHora;
    @Column
    private int estado;

    // RELATIONSHIPS
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idciclista")
    private Ciclista participante;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idprueba", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Prueba prueba;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({  
        @JoinColumn(name="idprueba"),  
        @JoinColumn(name="idvariante")
    }) 
    private Variante variante;

//Constructors, public getters and setters...
}
```

```java
@Embeddable
public class InscripcionPK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -582735882125091352L;

    int participante;
    int prueba;

    //Public getters and setters, hashcode, equals...
}
```

I don't paste the rest of mappings because they didn't caused me any problem so far, but they have also references to the current entity (bidirectional mappings).

I get the following exception when persisting a "Inscripcion" object:

```
...
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Parameter index out of range (7 > number of parameters, which is 6).
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1377)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1306)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1500)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:53)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:435)
    ... 90 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Parameter index out of range (7 > number of parameters, which is 6).
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at sun.proxy.$Proxy211.setInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:280)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeSet(ComponentType.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrateId(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2784)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2753)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3025)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3469)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1213)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:402)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:104)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (7 > number of parameters, which is 6).
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3813)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3795)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3840)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInt(PreparedStatement.java:3784)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.PreparedStatementWrapper.setInt(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:399)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.PreparedStatementWrapper.setInt(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:190)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor82.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
```

If I put the "insertable = false, updatable = false" in the @JoinColum's at "variante", I get the following exception:

```
...
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`projectbike`.`inscripcion`, CONSTRAINT `fk_inscripcion_variante1` FOREIGN KEY (`idvariante`, `idprueba`) REFERENCES `variante` (`idvariante`, `idprueba`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTI)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1377)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1306)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1500)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:53)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:435)
    ... 90 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`projectbike`.`inscripcion`, CONSTRAINT `fk_inscripcion_variante1` FOREIGN KEY (`idvariante`, `idprueba`) REFERENCES `variante` (`idvariante`, `idprueba`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTI)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at sun.proxy.$Proxy233.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3028)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3469)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1213)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:402)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:104)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`projectbike`.`inscripcion`, CONSTRAINT `fk_inscripcion_variante1` FOREIGN KEY (`idvariante`, `idprueba`) REFERENCES `variante` (`idvariante`, `idprueba`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTI)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1040)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:875)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    ... 106 more
```

I dont Know if this is a Hibernate bug, if this case is not suported by JPA or if I'm missing something obvious.

---

**EDIT:**

I post also my `Variante` class, becaus it has a composite key too. I hope it helps:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="variante")
@IdClass(value=VariantePK.class)
public class Variante {
    //ATRIBUTOS
    @Id
    @Column(name="idvariante")
    private short id;
    @Column
    private String nombre;
    @Column
    private Integer longitud;
    @Column
    private Integer desnivelPos;
    @Column
    private boolean mostrarTrack;

    //RELACIONES
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="idprueba")
    private Prueba prueba;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="idrecorrido")
    private Recorrido recorrido;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "variante", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Inscripcion> inscripciones;

    // Consructors, getters and setters...
}
```

```java
public class VariantePK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3276237020478540672L;

    private short id;
    private Integer prueba;

    public VariantePK() {
        super();
    }

    //Constructors, getters, setters, hashcode, equals...
}
```

Comment: The `insertable=false, updatable=false` is only making things worse. When using `@IdClass` `@Embeddable` is not needed on the `InscripcionPK` class (don't know if it is causing issues). Also you may want to check that the fields of `InscripcionPK` should match the Id fields of the `Ciclista` and `Prueba` entity classes both in name and type.

Comment: So, if I understood well, both fields in InscripcionPK should match in type and **name**. It might be a problem here, because they dont match the name of the id fields neither in Ciclista nor in Prueba. Is there any way of matching the fields without changing the field name? maybe annotating them with a @Column(name="whatever") annotation?

Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: BTW without `ìnsertable=false, updatable=false` I get an exception telling me that `idprueba shoud be mapped as insert=false, update=false`.

Comment: The `@Column` annotation can only be used in entity classes to specify the name of the column in the database table. The annotation cannot be used with a a class used as an `@IdClass`. So you will have to refactor the names of the fields in your java classes match. If that causes them to no longer match your DB then use the `@Column` annotation to correct that.

Comment: I think hibernate is saying you need `insertable=false, updatable=false` because it is detecting an issue with the mappings. However I assume you want to be able to set the prueba field. Hibernates suggestion would make that impossible as it would never write (INSERT or UPDATE) the relation to the DB only read it from the DB.

Comment: Question updated with `Variante` entity and its corresponding IdClass. Maybe the problem is caused because Hibernate is unable to match the IdClass of `Variante` from the idClass of `Inscripcion`. A possible solution would be to duplicate `idprueba` field in the database, bout it would be redundancy prone so I discard that solution. I'll keep digging on.